# How to modify this star pattern code in java to get my desired output?

Tags: java

i want this pattern to print

```
*
**
*****
```

but output is showing like this

```
*
**
***
```

how to modify this code to get my desired output what condition should be included in if loop?

```
public class Star {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i,j;

        for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
            {
                if(j<=i)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint and execute step by step to understand what is going on in your code.

Comment: what is the logic between 1, 2, 5 ? do you mean this sequence ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872485/find-the-nth-term-of-1-2-5-10-13-26-29

Comment: i have used it for the number of columns to print 5 stars in the third row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can understand your sequence you can just use :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.join("",
            Collections.nCopies(i % 2 == 0 ? i : (i - 1) * 2 + 1, "*"))
    );
}
```

Outputs

```
*
**
*****
```

---

This mean :

```
i % 2 == 0 ? i : (i - 1) * 2 + 1
```

If i is odd then repeat the star i time else repeat it `(i - 1) * 2 + 1`

```
i             repeat 
1             1
2             2
3             5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=i*i+1;j++)
        {
            if(j==1){

                System.out.print("*");
                System.out.println();
            }
            else if(j%2==1) {
                System.out.print("*");
                //System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
```

using [mod](https://www.baeldung.com/modulo-java) operator you can get proper output.Java has one important arithmetical operator you may not be familiar with, %, also known as the modulus or remainder operator. The % operator returns the remainder of two numbers. For instance 10 % 3 is 1 because 10 divided by 3 leaves a remainder of 1. You can use % just as you might use any other more common operator like + or -.

Output:-

```
*
**
*****
*********
```

Iteration:-

```
i        j(repeat)
1        1
2        2
3        3
```